# How can I give priority to sibling components in the same location in React native?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am using styled-component in React native.

I have a component called FirstContain and a sibling component SecondContain, and each of these components has a button component.

At this time, FirstContain and SecondContain overlap and SecondButton hides FirstButton, but I want to put SecondButton higher and press SecondButton,

So I tried using zIndex and elevation, but to no avail. What should I do?

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const FirstContain = styled.View`
background-color: lightblue;
flex:1;
`;

const FirstButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
background: lavender;
`;


const SecondContain = styled.View`
position: absolute;
background-color: lightgreen;
flex:1;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left: 5%;
`;

const SecondButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
background-color: lightpink;
`;

const App = () => {


  const firstConfunc = () => {
    console.log("firstConfunc");
  }

  const secondfunc = () => {
    console.log("secondconfuc");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <FirstContain>
        <FirstButton
          onPress={firstConfunc}>

          <Text>FirstContain</Text>
        </FirstButton>
      </FirstContain>

      <SecondContain>
        <SecondButton
          onPress={secondfunc}>
          <Text>secondContainer</Text>
        </SecondButton>
      </SecondContain>
    </>
  );
};
```

this is my snack

https://snack.expo.dev/u0idGYTpA

[image]

Comment: can you add image of expected results or how you want it to look like

Comment: @BhavyaKoshiya as you can see the sanck, FirstButton and SecondButton are overlapped, I want SecondButton to have priority over FirstButton like z-Index

Comment: i don't understand what you mean bt SecondButton to have priority over FirstButton that's why i want visual representation so that i can have some idea

Comment: @BhavyaKoshiya i just updated my photo. as you can see The secondContainer button is above the FirstContainer button. I want the FirstContainer to be on top of the seconContainer using something like zIndex.

Comment: You want it like this? https://i.imgur.com/aZkcbMz.png

Comment: Do you want second button to overlap the complete first button ? Or you want first button to render in first row and second button in second row  or vice-versa ?

Comment: @Kailash 
I want the first button to overwrite the second button.

Comment: then remove left: 5% from the styles

Comment: @Kailash there is no way by using zindex?

Comment: I'm not sure of zIndex, but there is a way where you can completely overwrite the first button by second button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it like this: [image]
then change your these styles to this

```
const FirstContain = styled.View`
background-color: lightblue;
`;

const SecondContain = styled.View`
background-color: lightgreen;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is working perfect fine, same as you are expecting, You'll get some idea from this code -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("first")} style={{padding: 10, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("second")} style={{padding: 10, backgroundColor:'blue', position:'absolute', left: 0, right:  0, top: 0, bottom: 0}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
}
```

As per Your code, You should change this part to likewise :

```
const SecondContain = styled.View`
position: absolute;
background-color: lightgreen;
flex:1;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left: 0;
`;
```